# How to setup multiple vps in one hardware

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, vps, datacenter

I purchase a rack server hardware with 64GB ram now i want to create 8*8GB VPS so how can i do that.

I have 1 internet connection and 8 static IP from ISP, Now problem is how can i setup port forwarding.

Actually before buying rack server i test it on home PC which have i3 processor with 4gb ram, i purchased a static ip then i install centos 7 and cpanel in my pc and check my local ip which was 192.168.1.26 (assigned by my router) then i point my domain to static ip then setup port forwarding to the 192.168.1.26

now if i create 8 disk partition into my rack server then overall that is connected to same internet and router will assign 1 local IP to that rack server now how can i assign different static ip to different vps and how can setup port forwarding in router for different static IP to one local IP?

Comment: You should start by [reading what a VPS is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server).

Comment: Thank you so much, i will read it and its suggested articles also, thank you so much for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions for this scenario. The easiest one that come to my mind is creating a bridge of physical host and virtual machine interfaces. In this case your physical host and virtual machines will be in the same broadcast domain and you can assign public IPs directly without portforwarding and extra rounting.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am beginner so this is little bit hard for me, but i will research topic by topic like what is bridge connection and how to make it.

and then implement all this together to get complete solution.